# How to pass instance method calls on to instance property?

Tags: python, class, instance-methods

Is there a way to pass all instance calls other than a specified few to an instances's property? I am trying to figure out the easiest way to write a wrapper class for `PyMongo` as below:

```
class Mongo():   
    def __init__(self, db_name, collection_name):
        self.client = MongoClient()
        self.collection = self.client[db_name][collection_name]
```

It would be really nice if there were a way to say `pass all self.function calls to self.collection unless you are calling something in this list: [__init__, __dict__, etc...]`. Is there a language feature that would allow me to do this? The only thing I can think of is doing something with `__call__` where the function name would be the value passed to `__call__` but it seems like it would get dicey as far as dealing with varying numbers and types of parameters. I am envisioning something like:

```
def __call__(self, value, *args, **kargs):
    func = getattr(self.test, value)
    func(self.test, *args, **kargs)
```

I haven't got the above working yet. In particular, I am passing too many arguments. Passing `args, kargs` or `*args, **kargs` does not sort itself out the way I'd hoped. **What do I need to do so that I can pass whatever arguments the user specified to whatever function the user specified?** (Complete minimal working example pasted at end of question)

However, even if I can get the above working, the notation is clunky. I'd really like to be able to do something more like:

```
f.f1(4,5)
```

rather than

```
f("f1", 4, 5)
```

**Are there better alternatives to this `__call__` scenario sketched above even if I can get it working as desired?**

Here's the code that's not working:

```
class test1():
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test

    def __call__(self, value, *args, **kargs):
        func = getattr(self.test, value)
        func(args, kargs)

class test2():
    def f1(a, b):
        print(a+b)

    def f2(stringy):
        print(stringy)

    def f3(a = 7, b = 14):
        print("a is %d and b is %b"%(a,b))


def main():
    t2 = test2()
    t1 = test1(t2)
    t1("f1",4, 5) #gives an error that I am passing 3 args instead of the 2 specified by func definition

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fairly simply intercept attribute access by defining `__getattr__` on your class. This is called whenever you access an attribute that doesn't actually exist in that instance; so you can pass them on to `self.collection`.

There's not even really a need to distinguish between methods and other attributes; the access is done before the call, so returning the collection's method will allow Python to do the right thing.

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return getattr(self.collection, attr)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this much simpler solution. Performance is not critical for me here so I'm not worried, but in general would you expect a performance hit for doing this?